# webservice or script to convert an iCal feed to XML

Tags: xml, parsing, icalendar

im searching an webservice or a script that converts an iCal Feed to XML so I can process it further.

I already tried Yahoo Pipes, but it does not support a proper XML output format.

Any suggestions or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: here's a Javascript library: http://code.google.com/p/ijp/source/browse/trunk/ijp/ijp-0.6.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use google calendar: its api will return an xml for the selected calendar.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I just imported the ical feed into my a google calendar and used www.google.com/calendar/feeds/<id>%40import.calendar.google.com/public/full to get an xml representation